# Replacing Ajax.BeginForm with jquery script

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I had an Ajax.BeginForm in my partial view but had issues with a nested form, for this reason I would like to use a jquery script to replace the Ajax.BeginForm and achieve tesame result.

This was the Ajax.BeginForm I used first:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateIngredient", "Recipe", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "create-ingredient", HttpMethod = "Post", OnComplete = "ClearTextboxes" }, new { @id = "createIngredient" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, "Custom Ingredient")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.addIngredient, new { @id = "addIngredient" })
    <input type="submit" id="createButton" value="Create" class="default-btn small-button light-border" onclick="$('#SelectedIngredient').append('<option>' + $('#addIngredient').val() + '</option>')" />
}
```

I have tried this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ClearTextboxes() {
    document.getElementById('addIngredient').value = ''
}

$(function () {
    $("#createButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Recipe/CreateIngredient",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But when clicking on the button it goes to the SubmitRecipe HttpPost instead of the CreateIngredient HttpPost

Submit.cshtml View:

http://pastebin.com/GdKmK6V6

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the `CreateIngredient()` method, but because you have not cancelled the default submit, you are also hitting the `SubmitRecipe()`.

Change the button to

```
<input type="button" id="createButton" ....
```

so it no longer submits the parent form, or cancel the default action

```
$("#createButton").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateIngredient", "Recipe")', // use Url.Action()
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false; // add this
});
```

Note that you have nested forms which is invalid html and you need to move the inner form to below the outer form. Your also not sending any data to the `CreateIngredient()` ingredient method. You have not shown the method, but assuming it has a paramater `string ingredient`, you would need to add

```
data: { ingredient: $('#addingredient').val() },`
```

to the ajax function

Comment: When changing the button type from submit to button it seems to break it

Comment: Because of you nested forms, and the fact you not sending any data. If you do not want to move the inner form, the just delete it. All you need is the label, textbox and button (the `<form>` tags are not required)

Comment: I don't have any nested forms right now, _CreateIngredient looks like this: http://pastebin.com/W6k6kCyc and _AddIngredient just has a DropdownListFor and ListBoxFor with 2 labels. With the data do you mean function(data)?

Comment: You need to remove the `onclick` in the button and append the option in the success callback of the ajax call. You also need to remove the scripts from the partial and put them in the main view (scripts should never be in partials)

Comment: By `data`, I mean that you not sending any information to the method (see the last part of the answer)

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, will remember to put scripts in the main view in the future. Still can't seem to get the <input type="button"> working, this is my newest code i'm using right now: http://pastebin.com/gxHYs5SD

Comment: What you have shown would appear to work fine. What is not working? What errors are you getting in the browser console? You have not shown your `CreateIngredient()` so its hard to know if that may be the problem.

Comment: Console was giving $("#createButton").click(function () { error. I replaced the " " with ' ' and the error was gone, but when clicking on the button it still doesn't go to the post. My HttpPost CreateIngredient method is like this: http://pastebin.com/fHzJS20G

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109482/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-josephzigler).